# cmake order of execution of add_subdirectory command

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I have a dependency problem in my cmake configuration.
When I start building from root directory of the project, it always gives an error. When I disable `add_subdirectory(application)` where I use `LibCalcBin`, it builds the `library` successfully. Then, I can build the `application`.

Why cmake don't build the `library` first then the `application` as I have specified in the order of add_subdirectory commands. Is there any way to resolve this issue? Thanks.

## Error

```
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LibCalcBin
    linked by target "run" in directory ...
```

## ./CMakeList.txt (Root Directory)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(DLLAbstract)

# specify where to put executable
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# specify where to put binaries
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# compile and build library
add_subdirectory(library)

# compile and build application
add_subdirectory(application)
```

## ./library

```
set(src LibCalc.cpp Calculator.cpp)

add_definitions(-DDLL_EXPORT)

add_library(LibCalc SHARED ${src})
```

## ./application

```
set(Src main.cpp)

find_path(LibCalcHeader
    NAMES 
        LibCalc.hpp
    PATHS 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/library
)

find_library(LibCalcBin
    NAMES 
        LibCalc
    PATHS 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Debug
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Release
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin
)

include_directories(${LibCalcHeader})

add_executable(run ${Src})

target_link_libraries(run ${LibCalcBin})
```

Comment: Why are you searching for your library? Just do `target_link_libraries(run LibCalc)`

Comment: @arrowd I was testing cmake for simple case-studies and wanted show a case-study for find_library function. However, in this case just using `target_link_libraries` will automatically create dependency between application and library so that it will solve my problem. You can post an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_library` command is used to locate libraries, which aren't part of your project. For libraries created by `add_library` command no special treatment is needed and you can use target name in `target_link_libraries` call:

```
target_link_libraries(run LibCalc)
```